# concat two videos with same format

Tags: ffmpeg, video, concatenation, h.265

I'm trying to concat two videos that have very similar formats :

```
Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1037 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.6.101 libx265
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 298 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Surround
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

and

```
 Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 312 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 224 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

But the final concatenated video ends up freezing over the first part (where the first video plays). Audio works fine but video shows either a freeze frame or a bunch of corrupted frames. Not sure what's wrong because the video codec, pixel format, video codec... seem to match.

I'm using `ffmpeg -f concat -i conc.txt -c copy output.mp4` with a conc.txt file containing :

```
1.mp4
2.mp4
```

When I try to use this line to concat two videos that I cut from the same base video it works fine, so I'm guessing my problem has to do with the video properties that are not matching perfectly, but I can't figure out which one.

To clarify my usecase : 2.mp4 is an episode of a show cut without the intro. 1.mp4 is an alternative intro of a show. I want to add the intro back into the episode. I don't want to have to reencode each episode while concatenating them, so I want to keep the `-c copy` argument. I can reencode the alternative intro 1.mp4 indivudally because I'll only have to do it once. But I can't seem to reencode the intro to match the episode properties so that the concat works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "I'm trying to concat two videos" - How?

Comment: I'm using `ffmpeg -f concat -i conc.txt -c copy output.mp4` with a conc.txt file containing :

    1.mp4

    2.mp4

Comment: try it without the -c copy....

Comment: Yes but I don't want to reencode the whole final video, because I'm running this hundreds of time on different videos. I can reencode video 1.mp4 to match 2.mp4 but I don't want to reencode both.

Comment: Can you share the first 10 seconds of each vídeo with the actual codec each one uses?

Comment: Here's a link to about 10 seconds of each video, with the broken output video as well : https://we.tl/t-27qgjXQWYV . Besides the results of ffprobe that I pasted in my post, I don't have any other info on the codecs of the videos.

Answer (score 0):

First convert the intro video to match the main video:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -c:a copy 1_.mp4
```

then change the conc.txt list to match 1_.mp4 or delete 1.mp4 and rename 1_.mp4 to 1.mp4....

Next:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -f concat -i conc.txt -c copy out.mp4
```

[out.mp4](https://files.catbox.moe/1xfvvk.mp4)

Comment: I'm so sorry, I mixed up the two files. The intro I sent you is supposed to be file 2.mp4, the episode is supposed to be 1.mp4, so I'd have to convert 2.mp4 to match 1.mp4. Your answer worked though, so I guess it's only a matter of finding the right codec/format to convert 2.mp4 to match 1.mp4?

Comment: Yes, I guess you just have to invert the order in the conc.txt and match both files by converting the intro, the differences that I noticed is that they use sligtly different color profiles and a different version of the encoder: vídeo1: Color profile: yuv420p10le(tv), Encoder: Lavf60.4.100 - 
video2: Color profile: yuv420p10le(tv, bt709, progressive), Encoder: Lavc60.6.101, maybe that bt709 in the color profile is the problem?